# Are Monad instances uniquely determined by their Applicative instances?

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative, category-theory

In [To what extent are Applicative/Monad instances uniquely determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32931549/1333025) I asked if the for a given data type the instances are uniquely determined (which is not the case). However, a related but different question is:

**If we have a data type with an `Applicative` instance, can it have more than one valid `Monad` instance?** Or in other words, is the corresponding monad uniquely determined, if it exists?

Comment: I think [Ørjan Johansen's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32932140/1477667) to your previous question (specifically the addendum) should answer this one.

Comment: @dfeuer You're right, I forgot about that addendum, that's indeed the answer.