# A type constructor IS a monad or HAS a monad?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, language-agnostic, category-theory

People usually say a type IS a monad.

In some functional languages and libraries (like Scala/Scalaz), you have a type constructor like List or Option, and you can define a Monad implementation that is separated from the original type. So basically there's nothing that forbids you in the type system from creating distinct instances of Monad for the same type constructor.

---

- is it possible for a type constructor to have multiple monads?
- if yes, can you provide any meaningful example of that? any "artificial" one?
- what about monoids, applicatives... ?

Comment: [Monad instances aren't unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931549/to-what-extent-are-applicative-monad-instances-uniquely-determined). The type system doesn't allow multiple instances for one type, but you can define new instances with newtype.

Comment: Thanks @Cubic. I'll try to read that but I'm not much familiar with Haskell at the moment. This question is quite language agnostic

Comment: Minor terminology point: `List` and `Option` are not types, since we can't really have e.g. `def f(x: Option) = ...` (I think even Scala disallow this, but I'm not 100% sure because of JVM's erasure). Only e.g. `List[Int], Option[Bool]` are types. In Haskell, we call things like `List,Option` type constructors, having kind `* -> *`. In Scala I don't know. Indeed, for a type like `Int` we do not say it is a monad, not that it has a monad. For `List[Int]` we could say, informally, that it is a monadic type.

Comment: thanks @chi I edited the question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can commonly find this all around in mathematics.

- A monad is a triple `(T, return, bind)` such that (...). When `bind` and `return` can be inferred from the context, we just refer to the monad as `T`.
- A monoid is a triple `(M, e, •)` such that (...). (...) we just refer to the monoid as `M`.
- A topological space is a pair `(S, T)` such that (...). We just refer to the topological space as `S`.
- A ring is a tuple `(V, 0, +, 1, ×)`...

So indeed, for a given type constructor `T` there may be multiple different definitions of `return` and `bind` that make a monad. To avoid having to refer to the triple every time, we can give `T` different names to disambiguate, in a way which corresponds to the `newtype` construct in Haskell. For example: `[]` vs `ZipList`, `State s` vs `ReaderT s (Writer s)`.

---

P.S. There is something artificial in saying that a monad or a monoid is a triple, especially given that there are different presentations: we could also say that a monad is a triple `(T, fmap, join)`, or that a monoid is a pair `(M, •)`, with the identity element hidden in the extra condition (because it is uniquely determined by `•` anyway). The ontology of mathematical structures is a more philosophical question that is outside the scope of SO (as well as outside my expertise). But a more prudent way to reformulate such definitions may be to say that "a monad is (defined|characterized) by a triple `(T, return, bind)`".

Comment: thanks for the math explaination. Do you have any example where there are multiple monads for the same type constructor? Preferably a pragmatic and useful example, but if not possible something "artificial" would also be interesting.

Comment: I gave the example of `State s` and `ReaderT s (Writer s)` above which both consist of functions `s -> (s, a)`. (`[]` and `ZipList` are examples of applicative functors, but `ZipList` is no monad.)  This [`Succs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/successors-0.1.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative-Successors.html) type has a monad instance useful to define shrinking, but there is also a product monad ([`Product Identity []`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Product.html#t:Product)).

Comment: If you literally meant examples of `Monad` instances for the same type constructor, that is not possible because instances must be unique.

Comment: I'm not sure to follow here. From `for a given type constructor T there may be multiple different definitions of return and  bind that make a monad` I understand it is possible to have 2 instances for the same time constructor. `(T, return1, bind1)` and `(T, return2, bind2)`

Comment: in math, yes; but in Haskell there can be defined only one instance of Monad for a given type. But, in Haskell there's also `newtype`, allowing us to call the same type by a different name; for this new name we *can* define another Monad instance. `ZipList` is an example (just that it is Applicative, not Monad, but it's the same principle).

Answer (score 2):

Insofar as you're asking about language usage, [Google says that the phrase “has a monad”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22has%20a%20monad%22&sa=G&dcr=0&gbv=1&sei=4RZaWv7tJ8_s_Qa6hZKQCg) doesn't seem to be commonly used in the way you're asking about.  Most real occurrences are in sentences such as, “The Haskell community **has a monad** problem.”  However, a few cases of vaguely similar usage do exist in the wild, such as, “the only thing which makes it ‘monadic‘ is that it has a `Monad` instance.”  That is, *monad* is often used as a synonym for *monadic*, modifying some other noun to produce a phrase (a monad problem, a `Monad` instance) that is sometimes used as the object of the verb *have*.

As for coding: in Haskell, a type can declare one `instance` of `Monad`, one of `Monoid` and so on. When a given type could have many such instances defined, such as how numbers are monoids under addition, multiplication, maximum, minimum and many other operations, Haskell defines separate types, such as `Sum Int`, a `Monoid` instance over `Int` where the operation is `+`, and `Product Int`, a `Monoid` instance where the operation is `*`.

I haven't comprehensively checked the tens of thousands of hits, though, so it's very possible there are better examples in there of what you're asking about.

The phrasing I've commonly seen for that is the one I just used: a *type* **is** a *category* **under** an *operation*.